# Call to undefined method DateTime::format but DateTime is working

Tags: php, datetime

I've gotten this really strange error all of a sudden in a legacy application we maintain.

> **Uncaught Error**: Call to undefined method DateTime::format() in
>   **PATH**/helpers.php:54

My relevant code is this:

```
function custom_date_format($str, $format=false){
    if(!$format){
        $format ="j M Y";
    }
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $str);
    if($date){
        return $date->format($format); // lineno 54
    }
    return '';
}
```

The server is running PHP 7 and `DateTime::createFromFormat` appears to be working so the `DateTime` object is working as it should.

It stopped working overnight (which I find really strange, and not sure if I believe it).

Any idea's of such strange errors?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `var_dump($date)` when it fails?

Comment: I'll try to retrieve it. I have no direct access for now to the server, but hope to retrieve it.

Comment: Are you sure DateTime is not conflicting with another DateTime class (i.e: `\Faker\Provider\DateTime` )? Is `$date instanceof \DateTime`

Comment: The helpers.php doesn't include any requires or includes.

Comment: What happens if you use `$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $str);`?

Comment: Good one, will try that when I have access!

Comment: Your code certainly works fine in a clean environment: https://3v4l.org/qXRvr

Answer (score 2):

We figured it out and the answer is not at all satisfying:

The bug was not repeatable in a reliable way. It was there intermittent. That is already cause for suspicion.

After some digging there were more processes reporting erratic behavior and it appears that a memory problem is the root cause. After migrating to a 'fresh' server all the problems are gone.

So apparently the DateTime object was not fully allocated in a way? The format function pointer was overwritten or something. But the faulty memory was causing it.